# PHP : Counting how many element in an array

Tags: php, arrays, element

I'm still newbie in PHP. I want to know how many element in an array. But my code bellow doesn't work.
anybody please help me..

here's my code..

```
<?php
$array = array(1,3,2,4,6);
$a=array_count_values($array);
echo $a;
?>
```

I want the  output will be 5.

Comment: Try to read a [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) with [api](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just use [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php),

```
$array = array(1,3,2,4,6);
$a=count($array);
echo $a;
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `count`:

```
<?php
$array = array(1,3,2,4,6);
$a=count($array);
echo $a;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you...I'm still newbie.. I've to learn many more about PHP I guest :)

Comment: Happy Coding Ahead :)

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need to do:

```
echo count($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone said `count()` is the way to do this. But just in case you are wondering why `array_count_values()` is not working - It is not used for counting number of elements in an array. It counts the number of occurrence of each value in your array returns an array of how many times each one occurs.

```
$array = array(1,3,2,4,6);
$a=array_count_values($array);
echo $a;
```

In this example you will get `array` as result because you are trying to echo a string. If you `print_r $a` you should get something like:

```
array([1]=>1,[2]=>1,[3]=>1....[6]=>1)
```

because all the values occur only once. If say you had `array(1,2,1)` then you would have got `array([1]=>2,[2]=>1)` because 1 occurs twice in the array